# Power save mode Android Lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, power-saving

Is there any way (with root or not) to enable or disable **programmatically** the android lollipop power save mode? I can't find any documentation about it.

Comment: No, you'd need to use the `DEVICE_POWER` permission which is not available for third party applications.